# Linux server programming

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I got this code from Andy Tanenbaum's book. I am trying to run it. It compiles and waits for connection. But when I type `localhost:886`, I see no effect either in the browser or the terminal. (It should echo a new connection string as per the code).

```
#define     SERVER_PORT         886     /* The port at which the server listens */
#define     BUF_SIZE        64032       /* The size of buffer for request and response */
#define     QUEUE_SIZE      10      /* Block transfer size */


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int     sock = 0, bnd = 0, lst = 0, fd = 0, sa = 0, bytes = 0, on = 1, conn_count = 0;
    char    buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct  sockaddr_in channel;            /* IP address holder */

    /* The address structure that binds with the socket */

    memset (&channel, 0, sizeof(channel));

    channel.sin_family      =   AF_INET;
    channel.sin_addr.s_addr     =   htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    channel.sin_port        =   htons (SERVER_PORT);

    /* Parital opening of the socket, while waiting for connection */

    sock                =   socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); /* Creates a new socket */
    if (sock < 0)
        printf ("Partial opening of the socket failed! Error: %d", sock);

    setsockopt (sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &on, sizeof(on));

    bnd             =   bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *) &channel, sizeof(channel));
    if (bnd < 0)
        printf ("Binding failure! Error: %d", bnd);

    lst             =   listen (sock, QUEUE_SIZE);
    if (lst < 0)
        printf ("Unable to listen on the socket! Error: %d", lst);

    /* The socket has been set-up. Wait for the connection and process it. */

    while (1) {

        conn_count      +=  1;
        printf ("Received connection: %d", conn_count); 
        sa          =   accept (sock, 0, 0);
        if (sa < 0)
            puts ("Unable to accept the socket opened for connection.");

        read (sa, buf, BUF_SIZE);

        puts (buf);     /* Output the string to the screen */

        close (sa);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `telnet localhost:886` on the command line.

Comment: You can confirm via `netstat` whether your program is actually listening on the appropriate port.

Comment: @Daniel `telnet` is disabled at my end.

Comment: @Michael @Flavius No item with `886` as port number features in `netstat`

Comment: I'm not suggesting you run a telnet _server_, I'm suggesting you use the telnet _client_ to try to connect to the server you're already running. Alternatively, netcat could be used.

Comment: @Daniel `telnet` command is itself disabled. I cannot use it for any purpose. 'netcat`, it seems, is not installed at all.

Comment: It's going to be very hard for you to test your networking software if you're not allowed to use software for testing networking. Perhaps you should find another development machine or use a VM.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks! May be I will get hold of a few testing software.

Comment: @Daniel: The syntax is `telnet localhost 886`, not `telnet localhost:886` (unless your version of `telnet` differs from mine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running this as sudo/root?  Your bind() might be failing because it is using privileged port.

---

[update from comment:]

Privileged ports are all ports below 1024.

Comment: And combined with the missing \n you haven't seen the error-message of the bind which is failing.

Comment: It is. The test program binds to some random port above 1024 (36969 in one of my launches), and when you connect to the port and send a string, it outputs: `Binding failure! Error: -1Received connection: 1test`. I guess, -1 is `EACCES`.

Comment: @Duck I was getting this error (after altering as per Jason's answer) but just at that time your answer poped and things seem to be working fine.

Comment: @Duck BTW, is there a way to know which are `privileged ports` and those which are not?

Comment: Or, better yet, change the `SERVER_PORT` constant to make it above 1024, rather than using root.

Comment: @john, *privileged ports* are all ports below 1024.

Comment: @john - everything ulidtko said.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a line-break '\n' at the end of your

```
 printf ("Received connection: %d\n", conn_count);
```

line.

Otherwise the stdout is not flushed directly and you see nothing.

Comment: Do that for the other lines as well, otherwise you won't see the error messages :/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `printf()` and `stdout`, try changing all your outputs to `fprintf()` and `stderr` which has no buffering ... I would do the same for the error messages as well so that they are output immediately when called and not buffered by `stdout`.

Finally, if you want to see what the error messages mean, use `strerror()` with the error number.  So you could so something like:

```
if (bnd < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Binding failure! Error: %s", strerror(bnd));
    exit(1);
}
```

Make sure for `strerror()` you also do an `include<string.h>` somewhere at the start of your code module.

Comment: also, do quit after errors, there is no reason to continue.. this seems to be a small toy server, something you shouldn't use in production. check http://www.unpbook.com/ for more serious stuff.

Comment: @Jason This helped now I am getting this: `Binding failure! Error: -1 Received connection: 1**
**` I am a bit perplexed, it is unable to bind the socket but it still functions!

Comment: it doesn't work. But a simple printf does not stop your program, you need some exits/returns or other things around the printed error message.

Comment: @john: I've updated my answer with some additional info that will help you debug the error messages a bit better